# Roslyn : How to get unresolved types

Tags: roslyn

I am using Roslyn's September 2012 CTP.

What is the most elegant way to get unresolved types in a c# code document? Eg. Type Guid requires the System namespace. Currently I have something like this:

```
            var semanticModel = (SemanticModel)document.GetSemanticModel();
            var tree = (SyntaxTree)document.GetSyntaxTree();

            //get unresolved types
            var unresolvedTypes = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>()
                .Where(x => semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(x).Symbol == null);
```

Is it correct to use IdentifierNameSyntax and GetSymbolInfo?

Also what is the difference between **GetSymbolInfo** and **GetTypeInfo**, they both look very similar to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several questions here.

Q: Is it correct to use `IdentifierNameSyntax`?
A: You probably want to use `SimpleNameSyntax` to handle resolving generic types.  Also, you may not want to look at ALL `SimpleNameSyntax` elements.  You will get false positives for things that are not actually in a type context (for example, imagine some code like `var x = Console();`

Q: Is it correct to use `GetSymbolInfo` and check for null?
A: Yes, this is the right thing to check here.

Q: What is the difference between `GetSymbolInfo` and `GetTypeInfo`?
A: For a syntax that represents a type name, there is no difference.  However, for arbitrary expressions `GetSymbolInfo` represents the specific symbol of the expression (for example, method call, indexer access, array access, overloaded operator, etc), and `GetTypeInfo` represents the resulting type (so that you would know what type to generate if you were adding a declaration for the expression).  Take for example the `InvocationExpressionSyntax` for "`myString.GetHashCode()`".  `GetSymbolInfo` would return the method symbol for `GetHashCode()`, while `GetTypeInfo` would return `System.Int32`.

Comment: Things like `var x = Console();` are not compilable, so it is ok to check for correctness of such a code, right? If not, what `SimpleNameSyntax` elements should be avoided?