# Roslyn: How to get candidate namespaces for unresolved types

Tags: c#, .net, types, namespaces, roslyn

Using Roslyn, is there a way I can get the list of candidate namespaces for each unresolved symbols in a list? If so, is there a way I can do a 'best match' for symbols with ambiguity, which belong to multiple possible namespaces?

I would like to generate a list of using statements for the unresolved symbols in a file. I am able to get the unresolved symbols from the semantic information using an approach like [Roslyn : How to get unresolved types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13833928/roslyn-how-to-get-unresolved-types), but could not find a way to arrive at the namespaces for these symbols from the referenced assemblies in the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I skimmed the Roslyn Repo and it looks like they use the `SymbolFinder` to retrieve information when they believe the user is missing a `using`: See [here.](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/03e30451ce7eb518e364b5806c524623424103e4/src/Features/Core/CodeFixes/Async/AbstractAddAsyncCodeFixProvider.cs#L40-L49)

As for finding the "best" match, I believe that's something you'll have to implement according to what you consider to be the "best" match. Visual Studio simply shows you all candidate `using` statements.

Here's a sample I threw together quickly to demonstrate `SymbolFinder`:

```
var ws = new AdhocWorkspace();
var solutionInfo = SolutionInfo.Create(SolutionId.CreateNewId();, VersionStamp.Create());
var solution = ws.AddSolution(solutionInfo);
var project = ws.AddProject("Sample", "C#");

//Add reference to mscorlib
var mscorlib = PortableExecutableReference.CreateFromAssembly(typeof(object).Assembly);
project = project.AddMetadataReference(mscorlib);
ws.TryApplyChanges(project.Solution);

string text = @"
class C
{
    void M()
    {
        //Missing a using System;
        Console.Write();
    }
}";
var sourceText = SourceText.From(text);

//Add document to project
var doc = ws.AddDocument(project.Id, "NewDoc", sourceText);
var model = doc.GetSemanticModelAsync().Result;
var unresolved = doc.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result.DescendantNodes().OfType<IdentifierNameSyntax>()
   .Where(x => model.GetSymbolInfo(x).Symbol == null);

foreach (var identifier in unresolved)
{
    var candidateUsings = SymbolFinder.FindDeclarationsAsync(doc.Project, identifier.Identifier.ValueText, ignoreCase: false).Result;

    //Process candidate usings...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Josh Varty, SymbolFinder's FindDeclaractions is what I was looking for. Extra credit for pointing out usage from the Roslyn source code.