# How to detect if a class uses Linq using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, linq, roslyn

Using **Roslyn**, I would like to detect if a class uses **Linq**.

**Assuming some code like:**

```
//...
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };       
var lowNums = 
    from n in numbers 
    where n < 5 
    select n; 
//...
```

*Assume also that the file this code does not include* `using System.Linq;`

I would like to be able to detect that there is a linq statement in the file and (say) automatically add `using System.Linq`. I would like to detect either query or method syntax for Linq.

**Is there a way I can detect this using Roslyn? I just want to know if the code is using Linq or not, and dont want to do any further processing.**

Comment: i think you might want to look for the appropriate tokens and after you have parsed the file check if any(or a minimal set) of them exist as tokens

Comment: I am using something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/29336378/4415401 but this does not seem to detect the linq code given in the example above. Would appreciate some working (or something that I can make work) snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a syntax tree, you can simply search for nodes of [`SyntaxKind.QueryExpression`](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Syntax/SyntaxKind.cs,409) or related node types.

For more information, open the file in VS2015 and look at the syntax visualizer to see exactly what the syntax tree looks like.

Comment: But this cannot detect `numbers.Where(n => n < 5)` version, right?

Comment: @JakubLinhart: Correct.  If you want to detect that, you'll need to define what you actually want (any method named `Where`? A specific LINQ provider? Any extension method with a lambda?).  And, you'll probably need a semantic model.